# Character array in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

Consider:

```
char [] chararray = txt1.Text;
```

How we do the same in Visual Basic 6.0?

Comment: As it's not possible to do exactly the same in VB 6 (as it doesn't have a character type), some more information would be helpful. What are you going to use it for?

Comment: actully i am just a beginner in vb6 ... what i want to do as- "i am going" is a string and i want to replace all gaps with * using char array. thank you

Comment: my basic quesstion is that how we will traverse all characters one by one using string/char array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends on what you eventually want to do.

You can, for example, do this in VB6:

```
Dim b() As Byte
b = Text1.Text
```

That way the `b` array will be resized to hold the Unicode data from `"string"` -- but then each character will be split across two bytes which is probably not what you want. This trick only works with `Byte`.

---

You also can do that:

```
Dim b() As Byte
b = StrConv(Text1.Text, vbFromUnicode)
```

Each letter will now occupy one byte, but the extended characters will be gone. Only do this if the current system code page contains the required characters.

---

You can copy the characters manually to an array:

```
Dim s() As String, i As Long
ReDim s(1 To Len(Text1.Text))

For i = 1 To UBound(s)
  s(i) = Mid$(Text1.Text, i, 1)
Next
```

---

Or you can even avoid creating an array at all, becase `Mid` also serves as an indexer operator that changes a character in place, without copying or allocating anything:

```
Dim s As String
s = Text1.Text

Mid$(s, 3, 1) = "!"
```

Comment: this all are very helpful for me , actully i am just a beginner in vb6 ... what i want to do as- "i am going" is a string and i want to replace all gaps with * using char array. thank you

Comment: @ashsih String manipulation in VB6 is usually done directly with strings, not with character arrays. Have you looked at the Replace function? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241892(v=VS.60).aspx It replaces all occurrences of a substring with another string. What exactly do you mean by "gaps"? Spaces? Try `str = Replace(str, " ", "*")`

Comment: i have already try this , but my basic quesstion is that how we will traverse all characters one by one using string/char array

Comment: @ashish By using a For loop, such as one used in the third example.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do the same in VB6, as it doesn't have a character data type.

You can split the string into an array of strings, each containing a single character:

```
Dim chararray(Len(txt1.Text) - 1) As String
For i = 1 to Len(txt1.Text)
  chararray(i - 1) = Mid(txt1.Text, i, 1)
Next
```

#### Edit:

To traverse a string and replace characters, you can simply loop over it's length and use the string function to manipulate it:

```
' Copy the value of the proeprty to a local variable
Dim text as String = txt1.Text
' Loop over the length of the string
For i = 1 to Len(text)
  ' Check the value of a character
  If Mid(text, i, 1) = " " Then
    ' Replace a character
    Mid(textx, i, 1) = "*"
  End If
Next
```

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Neither of the other methods do the same thing, so the code is of course not redundant. Please don't badmounth other answers like that without reason.

Comment: I don’t see it – what does your code differently from `b = StrConv(Text1.Text, vbFromUnicode)` (except of course for the extra byte value in the array)?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: It produces an array of strings, which I clearly pointed out in the answer, not an array of bytes.

Comment: Wow, carefully reading really helps. I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

VB6 has a `String` type so this code simply becomes:

```
Dim x As String
x = Text1.Text
```

You can manipulate that text in-place and manipulate individual characters using the VB6 string functions.

In the rare cases where you really need an array of the caracter codes, you need to declare a `Byte` array (VB has no `char` type), then you can simply assign the string to the array, or use `StrConv` to handle Unicode code points differently, as shown by @GSerg.

Answer (score 0):

[String To Array](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/visual-basic-4-5-6/code/216701/string-to-array):

```
Public Function str2Array(xString As String) As String()
Dim tmpArray() As String
Dim tmpchar As String

' /* For Each Character In The String */
For I = 1 To Len(xString)

    ' /* Retrieve The Character */
    tmpchar = Mid(xString, I, 1)
    ' /* Push It Into The Temporary Array */
    spush tmpArray, tmpchar
Next I

' /* Return The Array To The Calling Procedure */
str2Array = tmpArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the UNICODE value of each character of the string in this way:

Dim chararray(1 To Len(txt1.Text)) As Long

For i = 1 To Len(txt1.Text)
  chararray(i) = ASCW(Mid(Text1.Text, i, 1))
Next