# How to Remove Specific Special Characters

Tags: vb6

I have a string like `X5BC8373XXX`. Where X = a special character equals a Square.
I also have some special characters like `\n` but I remove them, but I can't remove the squares...
I'd like to know how to remove it.
I Found this method:

```
Dim Test As String
Test = Replace(Mscomm1.Input, Chr(160), Chr(64) 'Here I remove some of the special characters like \n
Test = Left$(Test, Len(Test) -2)
Test = Right$(Test, Len(Test) -2)
```

This method DOES remove those special characters, but it's also removing my first character `5`.
I realize that this method just remove 2 characters from the `left` and the `right`,
but how could I work around this to remove these special characters ?

Also I saw something with `vblF, CtrlF` something like this, but I couldn't work with this ;\

Comment: Change the `-2` parameter that you're passing to the `Left$` and `Right$` functions to another number?

Comment: @CodyGray I thought about that, but I'll have a differente lenght of `CardID` you know ? That's why I asked for maybe a different method.

Comment: Then you'll need to figure out what those "special characters" are and where they're coming from. Then you can `Replace` them, too. The reason they're displaying as a square/box is because your font doesn't have a glyph for that character. Use the debugger to see what the numeric value is.

Comment: The "square" you're referring to is probably just the generic placeholder used when a non-ASCII value is displayed in a font that doesn't include it, so the actual value isn't something you can look for; it's going to most likely be different for each of the "squares". Where are you getting the strings? If it's from a file, you can use a hex viewer or editor to see what's really there.

Comment: I know how to remove them in C#, but now I have to implement it in VB6 =\ And I know nothing about this language. In the debug it shows only a square... Thanks anyway @CodyGray

Comment: @KenWhite How may I do a ForEach in Each character in the string ? I tried it , but vb6 does not have the type `char`. ;s
I could make an `IF` through the string checking if it's a letter or number....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3820988/62576 has a way to read each character; see the third example that uses a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions. If you want to remove everything that's not a number or letter, you can use the code below. If there are other characters you want to keep, regular expressions are highly customizable, but can get a little confusing.

This also has the benefit of doing the whole string at once, instead of character by character.

You'll need to reference **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions** in your project.

```
Function AlphaNum(OldString As String)
   Dim RE As New RegExp
   RE.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]"
   RE.Global = True
   AlphaNum = RE.Replace(OldString, "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Cleaning out non-printable characters is easy enough.  One brute-force but easily customizable method might be:

```
Private Function Printable(ByVal Text As String) As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Char As String
    Dim Count As Long

    Printable = Text 'Allocate space, same width as original.
    For I = 1 To Len(Text)
        Char = Mid$(Text, I, 1)
        If Char Like "[ -~]" Then
            'Char was in the range " " through "~" so keep it.
            Count = Count + 1
            Mid$(Printable, Count, 1) = Char
        End If
    Next
    Printable = Left$(Printable, Count)
End Function

Private Sub Test()
    Dim S As String

    S = vbVerticalTab & "ABC" & vbFormFeed & vbBack
    Text1.Text = S 'Shows "boxes" or "?" depending on the font.
    Text2.Text = Printable(S)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove control characters (below CHR(32))

```
Function CleanString(strBefore As String) As String
  CleanString = ""
  Dim strAfter As String
  Dim intAscii As Integer
  Dim strTest As String
  Dim dblX As Double
  Dim dblLen As Double
  intLen = Len(strBefore)
  For dblX = 1 To dblLen
    strTest = Mid(strBefore, dblX, 1)
    If Asc(strTest) < 32 Then
      strTest = " "
    End If
    strAfter = strAfter & strTest
  Next dblX
  CleanString = strAfter
End Function
```